# Should I use loops for small iterations?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Is writing the a statement itself multiple times better than using a loop, if the iterations are small in number (<=5)? Basically, what I want to ask is does using loops effect the execution time and memory consumed for a code? Speaking in terms of memory, it appears that while loop does not consume any extra memory, whereas for loop uses only one extra variable. And, I don't really know about the difference in execution time.

So, are there any benefits of not using loops?

Comment: Your compiler will unroll the loop if it thinks it will be faster. You can safely assume that it is better than you at doing this. Write readable code.

Comment: The compiler will do some [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) for you automatically. You also should not care about the memory some loop counters need. Just write what is most readable until you can prove that it hurts your performance.

Comment: Other comments are good, but the point is - *It won't make a difference in performance!*. This is being *Penny Wise - Pound Foolish* (and you are in good company). In other words, if speed is what you want, learn how to get it. You don't get it by guessing. [*This is the method I and many others use.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)